# Problems with connection to Oracle database under sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Connecting to SYS user under sqldeveloper works fine.
Connecting to C##newcreateduser under sqlplus work fine.

But if I want using sqldeveloper for  connect to C##newcreateduser I just get loading... indefinitely and oracle.exe (OracleServiceNameOfDatabase) load average of one core of CPU. 
Any ideas?

Windows 10. Oracle 19c. sqldeveloper 19.2

Comment: When connected as sys, what do you get when you execute the following statement? "Select open_mode from v$database;"

Comment: READ WRITE
I reinstall sqldeveloper to new version and all works fine, probably there was corrupted installation.